# How to reuse one html code to another html using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav-item").click(function () {
      $(".content").load("about.html");
    });
});
```

```
 <section id="header">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link"  href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>    
              </ul>
            </div>  
          </nav>
</section>
<div class="content"></div>
          <div class="jumbotron "><h5>We make web app mobile app IOT and AI</h5>
                        <h1>We partner with startups founder</h1>
                        <h1>to build robust digital product</h1>
                        <div class="mt-5">
                        <button type="button">Start a Program</button>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="discription text-center">
                        <h1>Digital Agency In India</h1>
                        <h3>Strategic.Creative.Technical</h3>
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>
                          Iure dolores quo illo, et ipsa, hic consequuntur quae quia vero, nostrum aspernatur quisquam.<br>
                          Velit mollitia sapiente blanditiis animi illo, possimus repudiandae.<br>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">
                              <P class="text-center">want to bring idea to you life?<br>
                              <button type="button">Call Us Today</button>
                            </P>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col">
                            <P class="text-center">1 tiny idea + team work = Result.<br>
                            <button type="button ">Start your Project</button>
                          </P>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                          <h1 class="text-center"><p>EXPLORE YOUR WORK</p></h1>
                      </div>
                     <div class="Strack">
                       <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">

                            </P>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col">
                            <h3>S-Track</h3>
                            <p>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.<br>
                              Assumenda veritatis fuga quo illum quibusdam, fugiat, sit adipisci magni voluptas<br>
                              distinctio quisquam, facilis dolorem ab. Totam cupiditate aperiam delectus laudantium?<br>
                              Fugiat.
                            </p>
                            <button type="button ">Read More</button>
                          </P>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="SmartCrm">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col">
                             <h3>Smart CRM</h3>
                             <p>
                               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.<br>
                               Assumenda veritatis fuga quo illum quibusdam, fugiat, sit adipisci magni voluptas<br>
                               distinctio quisquam, facilis dolorem ab. Totam cupiditate aperiam delectus laudantium?<br>
                               Fugiat.
                             </p>
                             <button type="button ">Read More</button>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col">

                          </div>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                    <div class="Fleemarket">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col">

                             </P>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col">
                             <h3>O-Fleet management</h3>
                             <p>
                               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.<br>
                               Assumenda veritatis fuga quo illum quibusdam, fugiat, sit adipisci magni voluptas<br>
                               distinctio quisquam, facilis dolorem ab. Totam cupiditate aperiam delectus laudantium?<br>
                               Fugiat.
                             </p>
                             <button type="button ">Read More</button>
                           </P>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="Fleemarket text-center">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col">
                              Are you ready to start you project?
                             </P>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col">
                             <p>
                               Want to see our more work?
                             </p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="text-center">
                       OUR DIGITAL SERVICE
                     </div>
                     <div class="ods text-center">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-sm-3">
                              <h5>Strategy</h5>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-sm-3">
                              <h5>UI/UX</h5>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-sm-3">
                              <h5>development</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <h5>AI</h5>
                              </div>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                       <p class="text-center">FIND US HERE</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="cities text-center">
                     <div class="row">
                       <div class="col">
                           <p>Chennai</p> 
                       </div>
                       <div class="col">
                         <p>United Kingdom</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <h1>map</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                          Logo   
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                              <p> OUR services</p>
                              <p> Blog</p>
                              <p>Tech</p>
                              <p>our Process</p>
                              <p>About us</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col">
                              <p>Content</p>
                              <p>Career</p>
                              <p>Terms and Conditions</p>
                              <p>Privacy</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-5">

                            </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>

    </section>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to load one HTML to another main HTML using the load function.  I have a navbar which has 4 links such as ABOUT, CONTACT, BLOG, SUPPORT. So incase if I click on the link ABOUT, I want the new content to load and already existing content should go. I have already loaded the ABOUT content to main page  but I want already exsisting content to go and then new content to display.

Comment: you should probably give a shot to vuejs, it's so easy to learn, and will make things much simpler.

Comment: you mean the different sections are hidden within your page already and you want to show and hide each one when the links are clicked? Or you need to load the info from another file? It's not quite clear. It would help if you show us your code so far, and also explain what attempt you've made to solve this or at least research possible solutions.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the reply, I loaded HTML from another page. the main HTML has the header and footer which should stay and the new content should get added

Comment: @ADyson https://github.com/sushmitha1109/WEBSITE-Fsit-project- this is my code. thank you so much

Comment: @SushmithaKumaravel Thanks but as per the [site rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you must include the relevant part(s) of your code **within your question itself** (see item 1. on that page). External links can change or die over time, making the question useless for future readers. Please add that information into your question and I will gladly help you

Comment: @ADyson I have added my code Kindly help me out Please.

Comment: Thanks. But please show the content of about.html as well. So we can understand what goes wrong when you try and load it. And show the initial contents of the element with class "content" too, so we can understand what it looks like and how it would be affected. We need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can fully grasp all aspects of the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @ADyson actually the code works fine I have no idea how to make the header to stay when I click on About link, Instead of just redirecting it to another page I want my new HTML to load in the main page where my hear is still available. I don't want to copy-paste my navbar code or create a file and include it to my new file

Comment: ok. But to understand why you have a problem we need to see the full picture as I mentioned.

Comment: sure I will post my full code,There no error in my code just want an idea, to know how to load a page when I click on my navbar and the nave bar should still stay

Comment: @ADyson THANK you so much for being patient and replying me I have posted my full code.

Comment: As far as I can see you still haven't posted the contents of about.html

Comment: Yes I didn't post any content I have a headline saying "About Us" just want to know how to add this to main HTML on click nav bar where the main HTML goes aways and loads the about.html page

Answer (score -1):

PHP gives out native include and requires functions, but if using HTML, I found this working and useful: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

For removing the body part, you can write a JavaScript function to hide the elements.